# Переменная не существует внутри запроса plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Я пытаюсь прикрутить к БД postgres функцию, которая при вызове выгружала бы данные за промежуток времени в файл на сервере. Проблема в том, что при попытке использовать переданное значение внутри функции я получаю ошибку "столбец не существует". Ниже код функции.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.create_report(
    datefrom timestamp with time zone,
    dateto timestamp with time zone)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    AS

$BODY$
begin
SET timezone = 'Europe/Volgograd';
COPY(
SELECT 
DATE(tickets.datetrip) as "Дата поездки",
CASE WHEN tickets.datetrip < DATE(tickets.datetrip) + interval '3 hour' 
                 THEN DATE(tickets.datetrip - interval '1 day')
                ELSE DATE(tickets.datetrip) END as "Дата поездки +3часа",

DATE(tickets.dateins) as "Дата регистрации",
DATE(receipts.receiptdate) as "Дата фискализации",

SUM (CASE WHEN tickets.paymenttype = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Кол-во наличными",
SUM (CASE WHEN tickets.paymenttype = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Кол-во безналичными",
SUM (CASE WHEN tickets.paymenttype = 1 THEN tickets.price/100 ELSE 0 END) as "Сумма наличными",
SUM (CASE WHEN tickets.paymenttype = 2 THEN tickets.price/100 ELSE 0 END) as "Сумма безналичными"

                FROM dbo.tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.receipts on (tickets.ticketid = receipts.ticketid)
                WHERE receipts.receiptdate between datefrom and dateto

                GROUP BY DATE(tickets.datetrip),
                                               CASE WHEN tickets.datetrip < DATE(tickets.datetrip) + interval '3 hour' 
                                                               THEN DATE(tickets.datetrip - interval '1 day')
                                                              ELSE DATE(tickets.datetrip) END,

                                               DATE(tickets.dateins),
                                    DATE(receipts.receiptdate)

ORDER BY DATE(receipts.receiptdate)) TO 'D:\PostgresData\reports\1.csv' with (FORMAT csv, HEADER true, delimiter ';', ENCODING 'WIN1251');
end
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.create_report(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Ошибка, которую я получаю выглядит так:

```
ERROR:  ОШИБКА:  столбец "datefrom" не существует
LINE 17: ...
CONTEXT:  функция PL/pgSQL dbo.create_report(timestamp with time zone,timestamp with time zone), строка 4, оператор SQL-оператор


SQL state: 42703
```

Если вместо имени переменной поставить например now() то всё отрабатывает без ошибок. Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы получить значение переменной внутри этого запроса.

Comment: Похоже, там только через `EXECUTE`.  См.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22963085/1892060.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передать переменную или аргумент pl/pgsql в функцию COPY невозможно. Сработал вариант, который предложил  Ainar-G (к сожалению, не могу отметить комментарий как решение).

1) Формируем запрос динамически через format(), дублируя одиночные кавычки (слэшем не экранируется, только дублированием)

2) Исполняем его через EXECUTE.

У меня это выглядит так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.test(
    datefrom timestamp with time zone,
    dateto timestamp with time zone)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$
begin
EXECUTE format('COPY(
SELECT 
--какой-то код
FROM dbo.tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.receipts on (tickets.ticketid = receipts.ticketid)
WHERE receipts.receiptdate between %L and %L

GROUP BY DATE(tickets.datetrip)
--ещё код

ORDER BY DATE(receipts.receiptdate)) TO ''D:\\PostgresData\\reports\\1.csv'' with (FORMAT csv, HEADER true, delimiter '';'', ENCODING ''WIN1251'');', datefrom, dateto);
end
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.test(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Бонусом путь к файлу можно тоже сгенерировать динамически и передать в format